# Gradle Checkstyle Plugin Console Output

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

The Gradle Checkstyle plugin produces a lot of console output when Gradle is run with the `-info` option.  This output tends to swamp more useful output from other tasks.

The plugin is configured as follows:

```
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '6.15'
    configFile = file("$rootProject.projectDir/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
}
```

To see the problem, the build can be launched like this:

```
./gradlew clean checkStyleMain -info
```

The output then shows in the console as follows (edited for brevity!):

```
:core:checkstyleMain
Executing task ':core:checkstyleMain' (up-to-date check took 0.007 secs) due to:
....
[ant:xslt] Loading stylesheet <xsl:stylesheet    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
...
<xsl:template match="checkstyle">
    <html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css">
...
</xsl:template>
...
</xsl:stylesheet>
:core:checkstyleMain (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.878 secs.
```

The Gradle version is 2.10 and the Checkstyle plugin version is 6.15.

Does anyone know how to reduce or suppress the console output from the Checkstyle tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to temporarily change the log level for just one task, you can do:

```
checkstyleMain{
    logging.setLevel(LogLevel.LIFECYCLE)
}
```

Logging will revert back to default, in your case, `-info` once this task is completed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  In the first case, removing `-info` means I lose the output from all the other tasks, not just Checkstyle, so I don’t want to do that.  Your second suggestion just changes the output directory but leaves the (excessive) console output as it was and so unfortunately doesn’t solve the problem either.

Comment: I understood your question wrong. You want to keep the level of logging at info, except for the checkstyle task? Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @RaGe!  Your updated answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @RaGe is the solution to the problem I posed.  If you'd also like to reduce the Checkstyle output for the analysis of the `test` code in addition to the `main` code, use the following instead:

```
[checkstyleMain, checkstyleTest].each { task ->
    task.logging.setLevel(LogLevel.LIFECYCLE)
}
```