# Replacing Deprecated Gradle LoggingManager.setLevel() for Checkstyle

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

I use the Checkstyle plugin in my Gradle build.  Checkstyle produces too much output when Gradle is run with the `-info` flag.  I asked for help with this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275783/gradle-checkstyle-plugin-console-output) and the solution was to add the following to the Gradle script:

```
[checkstyleMain, checkstyleTest].each { task ->
    task.logging.setLevel(LogLevel.LIFECYCLE)
}
```

You can see the script in context [here](https://github.com/VocabHunter/VocabHunter/blob/1.0.16/build.gradle).  This solution was fine until a recent change in Gradle that made the `setLevel()` method deprecated.  I now see the following error with Gradle 2.14:

> LoggingManager.setLevel(LogLevel) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 3.0. If you are using this method to expose Ant logging messages, please use AntBuilder.setLifecycleLogLevel() instead.

Does anyone know how to silence excessive logging from the Checkstyle plugin when the `-info` Gradle flag is used without hitting the deprecation warning?

Comment: I ran into the same issue, googled the source-code, then saw `setLevelInternal`. works like a charm: `task.logging.setLevelInternal(LogLevel.LIFECYCLE)`. However, using an 'internal' method is always a bit risky

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
ant.lifecycleLogLevel = "ERROR"
```

instead of;

```
logging.setLevel(LogLevel.ERROR)
```

**Note:** Below are the possible levels for `ant.lifecycleLogLevel:`

```
DEBUG, VERBOSE, INFO, WARN, ERROR;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, in the case of the Checkstyle plugin, this doesn't fix the problem.  If I change the configuration in the question to use `task.ant.lifecycleLogLevel...` instead of `task.logging.setLevel`, I end up with the excessive output I want to avoid.